# How to insert a date that is 1 month prior to an existing date?

Tags: sql, date-formatting, advantage-database-server, dateadd

I have been asked to fill a field with date that is 1 month prior to a date in a another field in our database.

This would be like if the date is `1/16/13` I would then input into the new field the date of `12/16/12`.

The issue that I ran into is that some functions that are normal to native SQL databases do not exist in the same capacity in the Sybase Advantage Database I am using.

`DATEADD` for instance is not available from what I have experienced thus far.

So I have used the semi equivalent `TIMESTAMPADD` function. I started getting an error right when I thought I had it figured out so here is where I feel the issue is, but I do not know what the issue is:

```
INSERT INTO 
  Normalization
(
  memotext
)
SELECT 
  TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_MONTH, -1, memotext)
FROM 
  eqanswer
WHERE 
      entityrole = 'MTG_PROP_FIGS'
  AND fieldnum   = 22
```

I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR IN SCRIPT: poQuery: Error 7200:  AQE Error:  State = S0000;   NativeError = 2124;  [iAnywhere Solutions][Advantage SQL Engine]Invalid operand for operator: <assignment>
```

Comment: Your SQL Statement indicates that you might be reading from a Memo field versus a Timestamp / Date field.

I suspect that one of your rows may have data that can not necessarily be converted to a timestamp thus giving you an error.

Comment: The field that I am working with is a Char 64 field. I just wish the error was more specific so that I would know the data that is causing this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ideal solution would be to have a `TIMESTAMP` column instead of a `CHAR` (or `MEMO`, etc.) column in your database.

You have to convert from your character field to a timestamp field in order to use the `TIMESTAMPADD` function.

For example this will output `2012-12-16`:

```
SELECT
  LEFT(CONVERT(TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_MONTH, -1, CONVERT('2013-01-16 00:00:00', SQL_TIMESTAMP)), SQL_CHAR), 10) 
FROM 
  system.iota
```

If your date format is not in `ISO 8601` you have to reformat the date string in input and output.

If it contains `01/16/13` (leading zeros) you can just use `SUBSTRING` to reformat the string:

```
DECLARE
  @Input CHAR(20);

SET
  @Input = '01/16/13';

SET
  @Input =
     '20' 
    + SUBSTRING(@Input, 7, 2) 
    + '-' 
    + SUBSTRING(@Input, 1, 2) 
    + '-' 
    + SUBSTRING(@Input, 4, 2) 
    + ' 00:00:00';

SELECT
  LEFT(CONVERT(TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_MONTH, -1, CONVERT(@Input, SQL_TIMESTAMP)), SQL_CHAR), 10) 
FROM 
  system.iota
```

If the database contains `1/16/13` (no leading zeros) you have to use a split string algorithm which is out of the scope of this question.

To reformat the output you can use `MONTH`, `DAY` and `YEAR`:

```
DECLARE
  @Input CHAR(20);

DECLARE
  @Temp TIMESTAMP;

SET
  @Input = '01/16/13';

SET
  @Input =
     '20' 
    + SUBSTRING(@Input, 7, 2) 
    + '-' 
    + SUBSTRING(@Input, 1, 2) 
    + '-' 
    + SUBSTRING(@Input, 4, 2) 
    + ' 00:00:00';

SET
  @Temp = TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_MONTH, -1, CONVERT(@Input, SQL_TIMESTAMP)) 
;

SELECT
  TRIM(CONVERT(MONTH(@Temp), SQL_CHAR)) + '/' + TRIM(CONVERT(DAY(@Temp), SQL_CHAR)) + '/' + TRIM(CONVERT(YEAR(@Temp), SQL_CHAR))
FROM 
  system.iota
```

I'd suggest you first figure out how to do this with variables like in my examples. You can then combine this with your `INSERT INTO .. SELECT` statement.

You should be aware that anything that isn't a valid date format may cause trouble (the whole statement not executing due to `CONVERT` errors and so on).

If anything is unclear you can comment or ask another question on specific problems you're still having.

Comment: Thanks for all the input!